# How to update shadowRoot/createShadowRoot with the new attachShadow

Tags: atom-editor

I'm trying to fix a broken old plugin : https://atom.io/packages/video-player

It doesn't work anymore and there is a warning for `shadowRoot` and `createShadowRoot` as depracated.

I commented the old code and updated 3 files with `attachShadow`. (Trying to do the same thing)

No more Warnings, but it just doesn't work.

```
//~ this.shadowRoot = this.createShadowRoot();
//~ this.shadowRoot.appendChild(this.videoPlayer);
this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).appendChild(this.videoPlayer);


//~ this.shadowRoot = this.createShadowRoot();
this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });


//~ this.shadowRoot = this.createShadowRoot();
//~ this.shadowRoot.appendChild(this.videoPlayer);
this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).appendChild(this.videoPlayer);
```

Comment: Maybe you can be more specific what doesn't work. Does the player not work functionally or is the shadow root missing from the DOM? Can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we get a bit more context?

Comment: Oh, thanks for this seemingly obvious answer... I thought attachShadow didn't work or implemented differently. (I have never personnaly used any of them or didn't do anything in Atom.) But by checking details, it seems that the video src wasn't set by the plugins, so it basically is another problem. (I can set it in the console and it is working)